# Must declare the table variable "@tablename" when using variabe in FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a procedure for deleting duplicate row where theres 3 variable where one variable will be for table name, one for duplicate column, and other for order by column.
I guess I am missing some concepts so please help me with that

```sql
create procedure dupchecker @tablename varchar(20), @dupcol varchar(20), @orderbycol varchar(20)
 as
 with dup as 
 ( select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by @dupcol order by @orderbycol) as [row number] 
 from @tablename)
 delete from dup where [row number] not in (1)
 go
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support variable replacement, `FROM @TableName` does *not* mean "`FROM` the table who's name is the same as the value in the variable `@TableName`" it means "`FROM` the table variable `@TableName`", which as the error tells you is not defined. YOu would have to use dynamic SQL and **securely** *inject* the values. This, in all honesty, has the smell of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Are you trying to live up to the DRY principle ?

Comment: Let's say you'll get to the point where this procedure works as expected. What's the point of deleting duplicate values from any arbitrary table without adding a unique constraint after that deletion?

Comment: This seems like the sort of task you are going to implement one-time to fix an existing bad-data scenario, so what's the point of building some sort of generic handle-any table   process? If your database(s) are prolific with duplicate data you need to implement the necessary validation and constraints to maintain/enforce data quality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic SQL here. Make sure to correctly quote names using `QUOTENAME`.

Also object names should be declared `sysname` which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128)`.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dupchecker
  @tablename sysname,
  @dupcol sysname,
  @orderbycol sysname
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
WITH dup AS (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ' + QUOTENAME(@dupcol) + ' ORDER BY ' + QUOTENAME(@orderbycol) + ') as rn
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + '
)
DELETE dup
WHERE rn > 1;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```